# Adapt paging UICollectionView height to currently visible UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a paging UICollectionView with horizontal FlowLayout inside a UIScrollView (more content above and below) that only shows one UICollectionViewCell at a time. Each cell has full width but dynamic height. Now I'd like to adjust the UICollectionView height whenever the cell is changed.

I already have a method that I call when the current or next "page" changes where I update the height constraint of the UICollectionView. It's already working if the next "page" is taller than the previous but it completely messes up when the next page is smaller than the current.

[GIF of current state (too big to include)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEfkh.jpg)

```
private func updateCardHeight() {
    guard let currentHeight: CGFloat = cardCollectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: currentIndexPath)?.frame.height,
        let nextHeight: CGFloat = cardCollectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: nextIndexPath)?.frame.height
        else { return }
    let height = max(currentHeight, nextHeight)
    
    guard cardsHeightConstraint.constant != height else { return }
    cardsHeightConstraint.constant = height
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

At some point the `layoutAttributesForItem(at:)` fails and returns a fixed height of `50` instead of approx. `300`. Did anyone try something similar already - I couldn't find anything and am a bit lost.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't want to go wrong but I think the problem is here: `guard cardsHeightConstraint.constant != height else { return }` . Could you publish a more complete code? I'd like to experiment.

Comment: Thanks @Gius unfortunately the guard is not an issue, as it only prevents another layout change for the same height values. I uploaded the test project to github, feel free to experiment: https://github.com/hannesjung/dynamic-cards

Comment: I took a quick look at the code and debugged it. I noticed that when moving from a high cell to a low cell (to the right) the value of nextPage is first increased and then decreased. But I have not yet had time to understand why, maybe it could help you solve. I placed a breakpoint in `updateCardHeight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hannes, I saw problem in your project(the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView). There are various ways to achieve it but currently, I can suggest the minimal way to fix it. You could implement "**UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**", and try this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     return self.cardCollectionView.frame.size
}
```

Hope it helpful for you.

Comment: thanks for checking but that's exactly what I want to achieve. I'd like to adjust the UICollectionView height to the currently focused cell, even if it's smaller than other cells

Comment: @Hannes try this code. It work like you want to achieve